# Adding react props to functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data from API that I want to show in another component that is a stateless function.

This is the state - `const [user, setUser] = useState([]);`
And this is the data I want to output in other components:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${search}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  setUser(data);
};
```

Things I tried for my other component is:

```
const ProfileImg = props => <img src={props.avatar_url} alt="avatar" />; // or props.user.avatar_url
```

I tried deconstructing as well but I cannot get the data.

---

This is the whole form component as what i have now that im trying to pass to other
smaller components.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Form = (props) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    // const [formVal, setForm] = useState('');
    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

    const updateSearch = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }
    const getSearch = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      getData();
      // setForm(search);
      setSearch('');
    }

    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${search}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data);
      // console.log(data);
    }

    return (
     <React.Fragment>
     <StyledForm onSubmit={getSearch}>
     <input type="text" value={search} onChange={updateSearch} placeholder="Search for a user" />
     </StyledForm>
     <div>
     <h2>{user.followers}</h2>
     </div>
     </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you explain how you explicitly passing the data ?!

Comment: And do you pass the user data to ProfileImg? Please give a [mcve]. What specifically did you try?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair can i post a screenshot here? If not then that's how i tried passing it, storing it in user, and then passing props and trying to use that user.followers or user.avatar_url in this case, but thats the part im trying to get

Comment: @jonrsharpe in my main form component i just did <h2>{user.followers}</h2> and im trying to pass that user which is stored in state in my other components but i have no idea how to do it, i thought passing props and then using props.user is gonna work, and i tried things like const {user} = props; those are the things i have tried

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the MRE. I would also strongly recommend basic tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want but please see below. You seemed to be close with the props on the `ProfileImage`, but needed a slight change as per below which renders the correct avatar:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const ProfileImg = props => <img src={props.user.avatar_url} alt="avatar" />;

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/h3h394`);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setUser(data);
    };

    getData();
});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <ProfileImg user={user}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```